# How to use tr() on the model used by QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, translation, tr

I have an SQL database and using querymodel to populate the table directly. But now I need to translate some of texts in the model.

How do I go about it?

Should I have to use delegates and use `tr()` in `paint()` function?

Comment: Do you want to translate the texts from database using tr? I'm afraid it is not intended for this - tr is for static texts.

Comment: Yes, exactly. If tr() can't be used, then can you please suggest what other ways possible for the same?

Comment: You might try to use `QCoreApplication::translate()` function for such a dynamic translation.

Comment: @vahancho can you please let me know with some example? Like I have to this inside a delegate?